# How can I do that by using single query in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I want to make passive them if a date is earlier than today from the recorded dates within database with update command.How can I do that by using single query in C#?

Colums: Tarih(nvarchar)  ,  Durum(nvarchar)

For example;

```
if tarih<Datetime.Today.Date is set Durum='PASİF'
```

Code:

```
string sorgu = "select BitTarihi from Abonelikler";
        SqlConnection gg = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand gg2 = new SqlCommand(sorgu,gg);
        SqlDataReader gg3;
        gg.Open();
       gg3= gg2.ExecuteReader();
       while (gg3.Read())
       {
           DateTime b1 = new DateTime();
           DateTime b2 = new DateTime();
           b1 = Convert.ToDateTime(gg3.GetString(0));
           b2 = DateTime.Today.Date;
           TimeSpan fark = new TimeSpan();
           fark = b2 - b1;
           if (fark.TotalDays > 0)
           {
               SqlConnection vv = new SqlConnection(constr);
               SqlCommand vv2 = new SqlCommand("update Abonelikler set Durum='PASİF' where BitTarihi='" + b1.ToShortDateString() + "'", vv);
               vv.Open();
               vv2.ExecuteNonQuery();
               vv.Close();
               vv2.Dispose();

           }


       }
        gg.Close();
       gg2.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

```
UPDATE Abonelikler SET Durum='PASIF' 
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DD, CONVERT(datetime, BitTarihi), GETDATE())>0
```

Also, please do not use concatenation of an SQL statement, use parameters. It's more safe and also sometimes concatenation of statement with parameters hampers server-side statement optimization.

Comment: Doesn't DateDiff return date-boundary differences rather than whole-day differences?

Comment: @Tao, yes, it "Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate". My guess that `BitTarihi` doesn't contain time part (or `if(fark.TotalDays >0)` wouldn't work correctly because of fractional nature of the `TimeSpan.TotalDays` property) -- and in that case DATEDIFF returns exactly what we want, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but your original psuedo-code above also does a date boundary check, so this is what you asked for.

Comment: @Dmitry - it's not clear to me whether the OP wants to update "Records more than 24 hours old" (which is exactly what the C# code above does, and what you can do with DateAdd), or "Records from yesterday or earlier", which is what your query does. I'm just calling attention to the fact that your code does not do the same as the OP's code.

Comment: @samjudson - who is your comment directed to?

Comment: @Tao, No, OP code doesn't do what you state. First, TimeSpan.TotalDays is not equal to zero even if the timespan is a second long (e.g. TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0).TotalDays is not equal to zero, it's more like 1.157407407e-05). Second, `b2` is initialized by `DateTime.Today.Date`. That means there's no time part and again, your statement about 24 hours is false.

Comment: @Dmitry - yikes, now I get it, I misread two things... missed the ".Date" and changed the ">0" to ">1". Sorry about the confusion, thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating the records why don't you decide the state at query level? Since you check this everyday there will be many unneeded updates.

```
SELECT BitTarihi, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, BitTarihi, GetDate()) = 0 THEN 'AKTIF' ELSE 'PASIF' END DURUM FROM Abonelikler
```

This way you won't have to update your records.